# how to explode data from csv file separated by double quotes and show in a html table via php

Tags: php, csv, file-upload, upload

enter code here

```html
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("uploads/$a", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        $row = $line[0];   
        $cells = explode("," , $row);
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($cells as $cell) {
            echo "<td> <input type='radio'>". htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

> **hello all my code is below..
>       i problem is i have a file like this
>
> ```
> "Huis en Inrichting;Lampen;Vloerlampen";;;
> "Notebook \""Colours\"" (House Doctor)";"Computers en Software;Laptops;Laptops en Notebooks";"Computers en
> ```
>
> Software;Laptops;Onderdelen, Toebehoren";"Cd's en
>   Dvd's;Dvd's;Drama";"Computers en Software;Laptops;Tassen en
>   Hoezen";"Kinderen en Baby's;Speelgoed;Overig"
>       Wieg (Bedhuisje);"Kinderen en Baby's;Babybenodigdheden;Babywiegjes en Ledikanten";"Kinderen en Baby's;Kindermeubilair;Inrichting en
>   Decoratie";"Antiek en Kunst;Antiek | Gebruiksvoorwerpen;Koper en
>   Brons";;
>       Set van 2 opbergdoosjes (Done by Deer);"Huis en Inrichting;Woonaccessoires;Overige";"Hobby en Vrije
>   tijd;Overige;Overige Hobby en Vrije tijd";"Kinderen en
>   Baby's;Speelgoed;Overig";"Antiek en Kunst;Curiosa en Brocante;Curiosa
>   en Brocante";"Kinderen en Baby's;Speelgoed;Knuffels en Pluche"
>       Set van 2 wandrekken 'Wire Powder' (Done by Deer);"Huis en Inrichting;Woonaccessoires;Wandplanken en
>   Boekenplanken";"Verzamelen;Overige;Militaria | Tweede
>   Wereldoorlog";"Kinderen en Baby's;Kindermeubilair;Inrichting en
>   Decoratie";"Sieraden, Tassen en Uiterlijk;Uiterlijk;Cosmetica en
>   Make-up";"Antiek en Kunst;Curiosa en Brocante;Curiosa en Brocante"
>       Kast met 8 vakken (Hübsch);"Huis en Inrichting;Kasten;Overige";*
>
> ```
> *Que. and i want to show in a table separated by double quotes..**
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function.
You can pass delimiter and enclosure:

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]]] )
```

You have also working example there:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Your delimiter is ; if i see right. So instead of:

```
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))
```

use

```
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";"))
```